# How to bind with Mode=OneWay and only propagate changes back on save?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

#### Question

How can I make it so that changes to a note are only propagated back to the list, when the `Save` button is clicked instead on "lost focus"?

And the `Save` button should only be enabled when the note has been changed.

#### UI

The example application looks like this:

[image: UI]

The current behaviour is:

- Clicking on a note puts its text into the `TextBox`; that's fine.
- The changed text from the `TextBox` gets written back to the list when the `TextBox` loses the focus (default binding behaviour); but I only want that to happend when the `Save` button is clicked.
- The `Save` button is always activated because the `CanExecute(object parameter)` isn't correctly implemented yet; it should only get activated when the `TextBox` text is different from the selected note's text.

#### My research so far

- Option 1: Some Internet sources say to bind a different property to the `TextBox` and to programmatically check whether it is different from the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView`. I would have hoped that there was a way without introducing a third property in addition to the already existing `ListOfNotes` and `SelectedNote`.
- Option 2: Some Internet sources recommend to configure `Mode=OneWay` so that clicking an item in the `ListView` updates the `TextBox`, but not the other way around. This sounds like the solution I would prefer, but I wasn't able to figure out from the code examples how to raise an event programmatically so that the change in the `TextBox` gets written back to the `ListView` when the `Save` button is clicked.

I've found other Stackoverflow questions that seem to be similar to mine, but the answers to those haven't helped me fix the problem:

- [WPF databinding after Save button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827903/wpf-databinding-after-save-button-click)

#### Code

This example currently does two-way binding on focus lost. How do I need to change it to get the above described behaviour?

https://github.com/lernkurve/WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton="clr-namespace:WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="188.636" Width="299.242">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton:MainWindowsViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="List of notes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="112" Width="129" Margin="0,24,0,0">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNotes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Margin="0,10,-2,0"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Change selected note" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="112" Width="151">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="89" Margin="0,0,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Margin="10,7,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Margin="10,35,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`MainWindowsViewModel.cs`**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton
{
    public class MainWindowsViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Note> ListOfNotes { get; set; }

        public Note SelectedNote { get; set; }

        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowsViewModel()
        {
            ListOfNotes = new ObservableCollection<Note>
            {
                new Note { Text = "Note 1" },
                new Note { Text = "Note 2" }
            };
            SaveCommand = new SaveCommand(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**`SaveCommand.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton
{
    public class SaveCommand : ICommand
    {
        private MainWindowsViewModel vm;

        public SaveCommand(MainWindowsViewModel vm)
        {
            this.vm = vm;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            // What should go here?
            return true;

            // Pseudo code
            // return (is the TextBox text different from the original note text)
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            // What should go here?

            // Pseudo code
            // Let WPF know that the TextBox text has changed
            // Invoke the binding so it propagates the TextBox text back to the list
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

**`Note.cs`**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton
{
    public class Note : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string text;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't edit the selected note directly? make a clone on selected item changed and bind the text to the clone, on save write the clone back to the selected item.

Comment: You don't. You give `Note` a Clone method. Pass the dialog/usercontrol/whatever a clone, and i if the user commits the changes, you replace the original with the clone,  or replace its property values with the clone's values.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Ed Plunkett: so you are both saying the only way is _Option 1_? If so how would I implement that with the given example? (I've updated the question with _Option 1_ and _Option 2_ so one can reference it in the discussions and answers).

Comment: get rid of the binding on your textbox and button completely and add a click event to your button that add's the text to your observablecollection

Comment: For using Option2, I'd just bind the NoteTextBox.Text as the CommandParameter for the SaveCommand. Also, I'd probably use `Mode.Explicit` or `UpdateSource=OneTime` to make sure that any unsaved modifications aren't erased if WPF decides to requery the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the text to the `CommandParameter` of the `SaveButton` so it gets passed to the Save method for updating.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="NoteTextBox" Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Text, Mode=OneTime}" ../>
 <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=NoteTextBox, Path=Text}", 
         Content="Save" />
```

and

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return vm.SelectedNote.Text != parameter as string;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    vm.SelectedNote.Text = parameter as string;
}
```

Comment: Will OneTime work correctly if you choose a new item from the listbox? Shouldent it be OneWay?

Comment: @Scott I have no idea, the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) said "*Updates the binding target when the application starts or **when the data context changes**.*", so I am thinking it should be fine. I'd recommend testing to double-check though if this is the route you are going with your application. I'd want to avoid `OneWay` if possible because I know bindings will re-query values sometimes if things get unloaded, such as if control becomes non-visible, or application is minimized too long and resources are needed elsewhere.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I tried it and `OneTime` did _not_ work, but `OneWay` did.

Comment: This approach isn't appropriate if you have more than 1 property value to save. I suppose you could bind `CommandParameter` to a property that returns a tuple/value-tuple or other DTO...

Answer (score 2):

Option one is the easiest to implement, you will need to clone the `Note` object and set it to a separate property.

in your xaml, change your list view to the following so it now binds the `SelectedIndex` instead of the `SelectedItem`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNotes}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ...
```

And change TextBox to the following so it updates the binding as you type

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedNote.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ...
```

In Note.cs we add the `Clone()` method.

```
public class Note : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Note Clone()
    {
        return new Note()
        {
            Text = this.Text
        };
    }

    //... The rest stays the same
}
```

In MainWindowsViewModel.cs we add new properties for the `SelectedIndex` and clone the object when we detect a index has changed. We also need to add INotifyPropertyChanged so we can update the `SelectedNote` from the codebehind when we do the `Clone()`

```
public class MainWindowsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _selectedIndex = -1;
    private Note _selectedNote;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedIndex.Equals(value))
                return;

            _selectedIndex = value;

            CloneSelectedNote();
        }
    }

    private void CloneSelectedNote()
    {
        if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            SelectedNote = ListOfNotes[SelectedIndex].Clone();
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedNote = null;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Note SelectedNote
    {
        get { return _selectedNote; }
        set
        {
            if(Equals(_selectedNote, value))
                return;

            _selectedNote = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //... The rest stays the same
}
```

In SaveCommand.cs we add the logic for CanExecute and add the subscriptions to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`, this automatically makes it requery the CanExecute any time any binding changes. This can be a little ineffecent, if you wanted to you could expose a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` publicly but it would be `MainWindowsViewModel` responsibility to call it any time `vm.SelectedIndex` or `vm.SelectedNote.Text` changed.

```
public class SaveCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindowsViewModel vm;

    public SaveCommand(MainWindowsViewModel vm)
    {
        this.vm = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (vm.SelectedIndex < 0 || vm.SelectedNote == null)
            return false;

        return vm.ListOfNotes[vm.SelectedIndex].Text != vm.SelectedNote.Text;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        vm.ListOfNotes[vm.SelectedIndex] = vm.SelectedNote;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** Here is a updated version that does not use `CommandManager`

MainWindowsViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _selectedIndex = -1;
    private Note _selectedNote;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedIndex.Equals(value))
                return;

            _selectedIndex = value;

            CloneSelectedNote();
            RecheckSaveCommand();
        }
    }

    private void CloneSelectedNote()
    {
        if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            SelectedNote = ListOfNotes[SelectedIndex].Clone();
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedNote = null;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Note SelectedNote
    {
        get { return _selectedNote; }
        set
        {
            if(Equals(_selectedNote, value))
                return;

            if (_selectedNote != null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(_selectedNote, SelectedNoteTextChanged, nameof(Note.Text));
            }

            _selectedNote = value;
            if (_selectedNote != null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(_selectedNote, SelectedNoteTextChanged, nameof(Note.Text));
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void SelectedNoteTextChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        RecheckSaveCommand();
    }

    private void RecheckSaveCommand()
    {
        var command = this.SaveCommand as WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton.SaveCommand; //"this." and "WpfBindingOneWayWithSaveButton." are not necessary but I wanted to be explicit.
        if (command != null)
        {
            command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
    //...
 }
```

SaveCommand.cs

```
public class SaveCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindowsViewModel vm;

    public SaveCommand(MainWindowsViewModel vm)
    {
        this.vm = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (vm.SelectedIndex < 0 || vm.SelectedNote == null)
            return false;

        return vm.ListOfNotes[vm.SelectedIndex].Text != vm.SelectedNote.Text;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        vm.ListOfNotes[vm.SelectedIndex] = vm.SelectedNote;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }` for? I've googled but don't quite get it. Most of the examples on the Internet have it, but oftentimes they work without it.

Comment: Just updated the answer with some more details. What it does is it fires `CanExecuteChanged` any time any binding updates and more. We are using it for the updating binding part. When that event fires it tells WPF to call `CanExecute` again and see if the button should still be enabled or not.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for the explanation and updating the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `OneWay` but rather an `UpdateSourceTrigger` of value `Explicit`. [`BindingGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bindinggroup(v=vs.110).aspx) can do this for you though, here's a simple example:

```
<!-- For change observation -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>

<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup x:Name="EditGroup"></BindingGroup>
    </StackPanel.BindingGroup>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBox>

    <Button>
        <Button.Command>
            <local:CommitGroupCommand BindingGroup="{x:Reference EditGroup}"/>
        </Button.Command>
        Save
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public class CommitGroupCommand : ICommand
{
    public BindingGroup BindingGroup { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        BindingGroup.UpdateSources();
    }
}
```

(You could add a validation rule to your binding that requires the value to be different and use that for the `CanExecute` implementation.)

Using this method allows you to bind directly to the object you intend to edit, so you don't need to copy around values first.